# The same query on Sparql gives different results

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I read some questions related to my question, like 
[Same sparql not returning same results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023462/same-sparql-not-returning-same-results), but I think is a little different.

Consider this query which I submit into http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql (Virtuoso endpoint) and get 34 triples as a result. Result [Sparql](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%20?pred%20?obj%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Johann_Sebastian_Bach%3E%20?pred%20?obj%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%28langMatches%28lang%28?obj%29,%20%22%22%29%29%20%7C%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28langMatches%28lang%28?obj%29,%20%22EN%22%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
SELECT  ?pred ?obj
    WHERE { 
           <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Johann_Sebastian_Bach> ?pred ?obj
        FILTER((langMatches(lang(?obj), "")) ||
                      (langMatches(lang(?obj), "EN"))
          )
    }
```

Then, I used the same query in a code in python:

```
import rdflib
import rdfextras
rdfextras.registerplugins()

g=rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Johann_Sebastian_Bach")

PREFIX = """
                PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
"""

query = """
                SELECT ?pred ?obj
                    WHERE {dbp:Johann_Sebastian_Bach ?pred ?obj
                        FILTER( (langMatches(lang(?obj), "")) ||
                                (langMatches(lang(?obj), "EN")))}
"""
query = PREFIX + query
result_set = g.query(query)
print len(result_set)
```

This time, I get only 27 triples! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22943656/result.txt

I thought it could be related to the dbpedia site. I repeated these queries several time and always got the same difference. Therefore, I downloaded the RDF file to test it locally, and used the software Protége to simulate the Virtuoso endpoint. Even though, I still have different results from the sparql submitted into Protége and Python, 31 and 27. Is there any explanation for this difference? And how can I get the same result in both?

Comment: What are the statements in one and not the other?

Comment: I think they don't need to be declared in the Virtuoso endpoint, because it queries in DBpedia. But even if I remove the defaults prefix (PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>,                 PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>, PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>, PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>), it doesn't change the result in python.

Comment: I edited the code in python

Comment: What are the 31 results that you get?  What are the 27 results that you get?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suppose that the data from  http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql  (i.e., from DBpedia Live) is going to be the same as the data in the main DBpedia (what http://dbpedia.org/resource/Johann_Sebastian_Bach gives you)?  You're querying different datasets.

Comment: `lang` returns `""` for literals that don't have a language tag.  I'm not sure how `langMatches` handles `""`, but what happens if you change `langMatches(lang(?obj),"")` to `lang(?obj) = ""`?

Comment: There was a bug in earlier versions of RDFlib where `lang(x)` for a literal `x` that didn't have a language tag would return `None` instead of `""`.  It's mentioned in [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/rdfextras/issues/detail?id=15).

Comment: In trying to figure out what should happen here, I've asked a question on http://answers.semanticweb.com, [Is langMatches("","") true or false?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/25434/is-langmatches-true-or-false)

Comment: I know we've got a working solution now, but what version of rdflib are you using?  The later version of incorporates SPARQL querying into the code, so you don't need to import rdfextras, but I'm running into some trouble in trying to get your code to run under the later versions of rdflib

Comment: I'm using the version 4.0.1 and the python is 2.7.2. Yes, you are right! I've tested without rdfextras and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question is written, there are a few possible problems.  Based on the comments, the first one described here (about `lang`, `langMatches`, etc.) seems to be what you're *actually* running into, but I'll leave the descriptions of the other possible problems, in case someone else finds them useful.

### `lang`, `langMatches`, and the empty string

`lang` is defined to return `""` for literals with no language tags.  According to [RFC 4647](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4647.txt) §2.1, language tags are defined as follows:

> #### 2.1.  Basic Language Range
>
> A "basic language range" has the same syntax as an [RFC3066]
>   language    tag or is the single character "*".  The basic language
>   range was    originally described by HTTP/1.1 [RFC2616] and later
>   [RFC3066].  It    is defined by the following ABNF [RFC4234]:
>
> ```
> language-range   = (1*8ALPHA *("-" 1*8alphanum)) / "*"
> alphanum         = ALPHA / DIGIT
> ```

This means that `""` isn't actually a legal language tag. As [Jeen Broekstra pointed out on answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/25434/is-langmatches-true-false-or-an-error/25436), the SPARQL recommendation says:

> #### [17.2 Filter Evaluation](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#evaluation)
>
> SPARQL provides a subset of the functions and operators defined by
>   XQuery Operator Mapping. XQuery 1.0 section 2.2.3 Expression
>   Processing describes the invocation of XPath functions. The following
>   rules accommodate the differences in the data and execution models
>   between XQuery and SPARQL: …
>
> - Functions invoked with an
>     argument of the wrong type will produce a type error. Effective
>     boolean value arguments (labeled "xsd:boolean (EBV)" in the operator
>     mapping table below), are coerced to xsd:boolean using the EBV rules
>     in section 17.2.2.

Since `""` isn't a legal language tag, it might be considered "an argument of the wrong type [that] will produce a type error."  In that case, the `langMatches` invocation would produce an error, and that error will be treated as false in the `filter` expression.  Even if it doesn't return false for this reason, [RFC 4647](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4647.txt) §3.3.1, which describes how language tags and ranges are compared, doesn't say exactly what should happen in the comparison, since it's assuming legal language tags:

> Basic filtering compares basic language ranges to language tags. Each
>   basic language range in the language priority list is considered in
>   turn, according to priority.  A language range matches a particular
>   language tag if, in a case-insensitive comparison, it exactly equals
>   the tag, or **if it exactly equals a prefix of the tag such that the
>   first character following the prefix is "-"**.  For example, the
>   language-range "de-de" (German as used in Germany) matches the
>   language tag "de-DE-1996" (German as used in Germany, orthography of
>   1996), but not the language tags "de-Deva" (German as written in the
>   Devanagari script) or "de-Latn-DE" (German, Latin script, as used in
>   Germany).

Based on your comments and my local experiments, it appears that `langMatches(lang(?obj),"")` for literals without language tags (so really, `langMatches("","")`) is returning true in Virtuoso (as it's installed on DBpedia), Jena's ARQ (from my experiments), and Proégé (from our experiments), and it's returning false (or an error that's coerced to false) in RDFlib.

In either case, since `lang` is defined to return `""` for the literals without a language tag, , you should be able to reliably include them in your results by changing `langMatches(lang(?obj),"")` with `lang(?obj) = ""`.

### Issues with the data that you're using

You're not querying the same data.  The data that you download from

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Johann_Sebastian_Bach

is from *DBpedia*, but when you run a query against

- http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql,

you're running it against *DBpedia Live*, which may have different data.   If you run this query on the DBpedia Live endpoint and on the DBpedia endpoint, you get a different number of results:

```
SELECT count(*) WHERE { 
  dbpedia:Johann_Sebastian_Bach ?pred ?obj
  FILTER( langMatches(lang(?obj), "")  || langMatches(lang(?obj), "EN" ) )
}
```

[DBpedia Live results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20count%28%2a%29%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aJohann_Sebastian_Bach%20?pred%20?obj%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%28%20langMatches%28lang%28?obj%29,%20%22%22%29%20%20%7C%7C%20langMatches%28lang%28?obj%29,%20%22EN%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=0&debug=on) 31
[DBpedia results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20count%28%2a%29%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aJohann_Sebastian_Bach%20?pred%20?obj%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%28%20langMatches%28lang%28?obj%29,%20%22%22%29%20%20%7C%7C%20langMatches%28lang%28?obj%29,%20%22EN%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on) 34

### Issues with `distinct`

Another possible problem, though it doesn't seem to be the one that you're running into, is that your second query has a `distinct` modifier, but your first one doesn't.  That means that your second query could easily have fewer results than the first one.

If you run this query against the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) you should get 34 results, and that's the same whether or not you use the `distinct` modifiers, and it's the number that you should get if you download the data and run the same query against it.

```
select ?pred ?obj where { 
  dbpedia:Johann_Sebastian_Bach ?pred ?obj
  filter( langMatches(lang(?obj), "") || langMatches(lang(?obj), "EN") )
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?pred%20?obj%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aJohann_Sebastian_Bach%20?pred%20?obj%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28lang%28?obj%29,%20%22%22%29%20%7C%7C%20langMatches%28lang%28?obj%29,%20%22EN%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I removed the DISTINCT modidifier, and, as you mentioned, it didn't change the result. My main question is why the same query used in python and sparql (protege) ran against my local rdf data still gives me different results?

Comment: I've realised that these differences are related to these triples: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate 1685-03-21
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate 1750-07-28
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID 9906294
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRevisionID 546793436
http://dbpedia.org/property/dateOfBirth 21
http://dbpedia.org/property/dateOfDeath 28
http://dbpedia.org/property/id 24

Comment: @user2725174 Are you still running the first query against DBpedia Live?  DBpedia Live is _not the same data_ as the DBpedia release, which is what you get from http://dbpedia.org/resource/*`.  It's not surprising that you get different results if you query different data.  As I asked in a comment on the question, please update your question with the _actual_ different results that you're getting.

Comment: all have numbers in the objects! To be clear, I get less triples when I run the query in python. Could you explain that? Is there a way to get the same result in python?

Comment: the last comments were based on the rdf data downloaded from DBpedia. When I run the query in the sparql (protege) and python they are different

Comment: Of course they have numbers in the objects, that's to be expected because of your query.  That's not a surprise, right?  The lang of such a literal will match `""`.

Comment: @user2725174 Your question doesn't include anything about Protégé, only about Python and a webclient.  We can't diagnose where you're getting differences, if we can't see _what_ differences you're getting.  If you don't edit your question to show what results you're getting under one system and what results you're getting under another, we're _not_ going to be able to provide any help.

Comment: Yes, but these numbers are only in the query using protege. When I use python, they are not retrieved. These are the differences!

Comment: @user2725174 That's the first time that you've made it clear _what_ the differences are.  You're getting datatype literals that don't have a language tag when you run the query in Python, but with other query engines you do.  It would have been _much_ easier if you could have _shown_ those results in the question;  then someone else might have been able to _understand_ what was going on before this.  Now it boils down to this:  "This query … selects non-string literals as `?obj` when I use Protégé or DBpedia's Virtuoso, but these aren't selected when using Python's rdflib. Why?"

Comment: @user2725174 I don't have an answer for that yet, but _that's_ a much more concrete and specific question.

Comment: @user2725174 In a comment on the question, I added a possible workaround.  Please take a look at that and try it out, and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks again Joshua! Just to let you know, the problem was with the langMatches(lang(?obj),""). When I changed it to lang(?obj) = "", it worked!